# why i am getting attribute error though i have pygame in pip3 list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

When running the following code:

```
import pygame
print(pygame.__version__)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/mahesh/python/pygame.py", line 1, in 
>       import pygame   File "/home/mahesh/python/pygame.py", line 2, in 
>       print(pygame.**version**) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**version**'

Comment: try ```print(pygame.version.ver)```

Comment: It throws the same error again

Comment: You named you file `pygame.py`. That produces a name clash with the `pygame` library. You will have to rename your file.

Comment: **i got this error on changing it** import pygame
ImportError: bad magic number in 'pygame': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Answer (score 1):

You should pay closer attention to the error, it says that the `pygame` module had no `__version__` attribute.

you should try from within `python`:

1. `pygame.version.ver`
2. `pygame.version.vernum`

If you want directly from the terminal you should do:

`pip show pygame`

Comment: Name: pygame
Version: 1.9.6
Summary: Python Game Development
Home-page: https://www.pygame.org
Author: A community project.
Author-email: pygame@pygame.org
License: LGPL
Location: /home/mahesh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:

Comment: basically i have installed it in linux mint and i didn't know why it is not working though i have tried various types of installations in pygame ;).

Comment: @Mahesh I dont understand your comment, can you elaborate